# Java use object's class to create a generic type is this possible?

Tags: java, generics

Say I want to do..

```
public class Foo{

  public Foo(Object c){
      Bar<c> bar = new Bar();
  }
}


public class Bar<Type>{
......
}
```

Is something along the lines of this possible?

Ultimately I want to dynamically give Bar a type based off the data type passed in from "Object C". This is going to be parsed by another class.

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: If I remember correctly, generics are enforced at compile time.

Comment: A type parameter denotes - as the name states - a type. So between < and > a type - the name of a java class is expected. You want to put an object - an instance of a java class - there. This cannot work and has no meaning too.

Comment: The question is kind of wrong, because you're interested in the type of C and not C itself. In this case, @Boann gave the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
public <T> Foo(T c) {
    Bar<T> bar = new Bar<>();
}
```

Note however that this is based on the compile-time type of `c`, not the run-time type.

Comment: Thanks, this does work; now I'm trying to make sure I understand why.

Comment: @SEngineerJay Based on the edit in your question: "This is going to be parsed by another class" I'm not really sure this is useful, since it sounds like you will always call this constructor with a variable of compile-time type `Object`, so the generics will not really achieve much, and could be a nuisance if you want to pass the Bar object around. But it depends how you're using it. If it doesn't work out, expand your question with more detail on your goal, as there could be a different solution that would work better.

Comment: The parameter `c` is not used, therefore it should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

No, it really wouldn't make any sense because generics in Java only exist at compile-time, so unless you know something about `c` at that point, there's no advantage to be had by casting your `Bar` to a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Since type arguments are erased anyway, the new instance of `Bar` knows nothing of the type argument.  This code therefore reduces to

```
public Foo(Object c){
    Bar bar = new Bar();
}
```